# PHPExcel_Calculation_Exception: 10!I9 -> Formula Error: Unexpected ,

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, laravel-5.4

I am trying to upload a multi sheet excel file.

my code is like this

```
Excel::load($file_path, function($sheet) {

                $detail = $sheet->get();
                var_dump($detail);
           });
```

but I am getting following error

> PHPExcel_Calculation_Exception: 10!I9 -> Formula Error: Unexpected ,

Literally I don't have any other code in that file.

**Update**

My first ananlysis was that there is mistake in the file . then I changed my code to this

```
Excel::filter('chunk')->load($file_path, function($reader) use($file,&$detail) {

               foreach ($reader->get() as $sheet) {
                // $sheetTitle = $sheet->getTitle();
                 foreach($sheet->toArray as $row)
                 {

                 }
               }

           });
```

Some how this is working but in the columns its showing `null`

```
55 => Maatwebsite\Excel\Collections\CellCollection {#7429
      #title: null
      #items: array:1 [
        0 => null
      ]
    }
    56 => Maatwebsite\Excel\Collections\CellCollection {#7446
      #title: null
      #items: array:1 [
        0 => null
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Thanks

Comment: My educated guess, based on the detail that you've provided, would be that there's something in that file you're loading which the PHPExcel library recognises as a looking like a formula, but which it cannot evaluate for some reason

Comment: @MarkBaker well I was also thinking the same , Then i did bit of change in the  code `Excel::filter('chunk')->load($file_path, function($reader) use($file,&$detail) {
                
               foreach ($reader->get() as $sheet) {
                // $sheetTitle = $sheet->getTitle();
                 foreach($sheet->toArray as $row)
                 {
                    
                 }
               }
                
           });` have a look this is working

Comment: Do you know what type of file it is? CSV, xls, xlsx? What calculations it ay contain?

Comment: @MarkBaker its xls just normal excel sheet I dont think that there is any calbulation or formulae in it , umm can you tell me how i can remove the formulae if there is any

Comment: If it's a genuine (BIFF format) xls file; then there should be flag information in each cell indicating if that cell contains a formula to evaluate, or if it should be treated as a string; so it would be unusual for PHPExcel to try to evaluate an invalid formula, or to misinterpret a string as a formula in need of evaluation

Comment: @MarkBaker sorry for my silly behaviour , I just rechecked according to your steps provided and I found out there is one column which has formulae , Ill try to convert that into just text first then upload

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143881/discussion-between-vikram-and-mark-baker).

Comment: @MarkBaker would be glad if you could have a look on my file

Answer (score 1):

```
$rows = Excel::load('storage\\exports\\'. $fName)->get();
```

use this just change your path and file name